# Script em JavaScript não está executando

Tags: javascript, formulário

Estou com o seguinte problema...

Tenho esse código em **JS**:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    const regexCharactere = /<li>.[^<* ]+/;
    const regexEmail = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;;
    const nome = document.getElementsByClassName('nome');
    const email = document.getElementsByClassName('email');
    const buttonForm = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonForm');
    buttonForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert("testando");
        if(!regexEmail.test(email.value)  {

            alert('Formato do e-mail inválido');
            email.focus();
            e.preventDefault();

        }
        if(!regexCharactere.test(nome.value) {

            alert('Nome inválido');
            nome.focus();
            e.preventDefault();

        } 

    });
});
```

Estrutura **HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="#">

  <label class="left">Nome</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome">

  <label class="left">E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">

  <label class="left">Telefone/Celular</label>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="telefone" id="telfone" placeholder="Telefone/Celular">

  <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light cta btn-large btn-solicitar-modal pulse-hover buttonForm"> Solicitar curso </button>
  </form>
```

Quando eu tento injetar ele na minha página não aparece nenhum erro do `script`, porém não executa como eu esperava.

Já cheguei a fazer alguns testes:

- Acrescentei o `window` inicialmente para carregar o *script*
- Mudei alguns campos do meu HTML e do meu JS, porém mesmo assim não houve sucesso
- Tentei aplicar um `alert` (como mostra o script) para ver se capta, porém sem sucesso também.
- Mudei no `buttonForm.addEventListener('click', (e) => { /// }` para
          `buttonForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => { /// }` 
  porém não funcionou também

Qual o problema do meu *script*?

**Edit:** Caso não tenha sido claro o suficiente, vou realizar as mudanças.

Comment: Não seria `document.getElementsByClassName('buttonForm')[0]` ?

Comment: Eu não sei muito bem do que se trata pegar na posição [0]... Mas além desse formulário, possuem outros 3 formulários idênticos nas páginas (porém em resoluções diferentes)... Bom, pode me explicar qual motivo do [0]?

Comment: Seria interessante colocar um evento de `submit` no formulário invés de ser no botão.

Comment: Então, eu cheguei a trocar o button por uma variavel do formulário... Porém também não está ocorrendo nada: Ficou assim: `const form = document.forms['marketing'].value;`   e depois `form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {});`.

Comment: O que mais tem é erro no seu script, como, por exemplo, fechar os `(` dos `if`'s.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem @Sam, pode ser mais claro? Pois estou estabelecendo uma condição ali... Obrigado pela observação do erro no script, mas gostaria de entender melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem muitos erros no seu script. Provavelmente você não os está vendo no console porque o formulário está sendo submetido rapidamente a tempo de você não ver os erros mostrados no console, pois a página sofre um refresh rápido para o `#` no `action` do `form`.

**Erros:**

Os campos "nome" e "email" não possuem `class`, apenas `name` e `id`, logo o `document.getElementsByClassName` se torna inválido. Você poderia pegar o valor desses campos ou com `document.getElementsByName('name_do_campo')[0]` ou `document.getElementById('id_do_campo')`.

No caso do `document.getElementsByName` é necessário o índice `[0]` pois esse método retorna um *nodelist* (uma array). Já o `document.getElementById` não precisa de índice porque só pega um único elemento (veja que o nome do método está no singular).

O botão `submit` tem uma `class` e pode ser capturado com `document.getElementsByClassName('buttonForm')[0]`.

Outro erro é a regex onde falta escapar as barras delimitadoras `/` no meio da expressão:

```
/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
                ↑                                 ↑
```

Outro erro é que faltou fechar os parenteses dos `if`'s:

```
if(!regexEmail.test(email.value)) {
                                ↑
```

e

```
if(!regexCharactere.test(nome.value)) {
                                    ↑
```

Comment: Opa! Agradeço pelas correções, vou tentar ver se consigo agora. Esses pequenos erros nem reparei, realmente foi algo absurdo rs.

Comment: Tranquilo amigo. QQ dúvida é só falar.

Comment: não é uma dúvida e sim um conselho... Tem alguma apostila, curso, ou conteúdo de conhecimento sobre programação? Por onde começar, muitas vezes me acabo perdendo em conceitos básicos, outros não conheço a fundo (como estrutura de dados, árvores, posições, etc)... Se tiver poderia compartilhar o conhecimento conosco (comunidade)? Para nós (leigos e novos na parte de programação) é uma grande ajuda. Agradecemos desde já.

Comment: Cara, não conheço nenhum curso ou apostila, tudo que aprendi foi tentando fazer e muitas coisas aprendi aqui no site mesmo. Um bom site pra começar é o W3Schools. Lá tem muita coisa aproveitável para iniciantes.